# Best Practice in rails controller for model with multiple purposes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I hope you can help me with this.
I have a model `User` and two controllers `UserController` and `AdminController`. Also I have another model called `Article`( and a `ArticleController`).Also I have some relations between this models.

```
class User
  ...
  has_many :articles
end
```

I need my routes would look something like this :

```
resources :admin do
  ...
  resources :articles do
  end
end

resources :users
  ...
  resources :articles do
  end
end
```

So, I need both, common users and the admin, could create, list and delete articles. Since I only have one create, destroy, edit and update function for `ArticleController` how can I achieve what I want? . The deal is that after a common user creates an article, it needs to sent to a particular view in `User` views, and if the `Admin` creates an article, it needs to redirects to a particular view in `Admin` views, all this would be done by placing some `IF` clauses in the `create` function, depending on the previous url. Is that correct, is it a good practice. Maybe should I create all these views in the Article folder?. Other thing I came up with is creating different `create` functions in `ArticleController` and the same for edit, new and update functions.
Maybe the question is kind of silly, but I am kind of newbie in Ruby.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Namespace**

To expand on `David Underwood`'s answer, you're probably looking to use [`namespacing`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) in your app

This works by leading Rails to look for a `module` prepending the controllers in a particular `namespace`, like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :admin do
   resources :articles, only: :show #-> domain.com/admin/articles/15
end
```

This leads Rails to look for the `articles` controller in:

```
#app/controllers/admin/articles_controller.rb
class Admin::ArticlesController < ApplicationController
end
```

--

This will allow you to define actions which only occur in the `admin` namespace, thus giving you the capacity to create / edit / update the various records you want

I think this is the general answer you need. In regards to sending the user to different views after the controller, you'll be able to use `redirect_to` in both controllers

We use namespacing to create `admin` areas in our apps

Answer (score 2):

Use two controllers.

In your controllers directory create a sub-folder called `admin` and in there create a controller called `Admin::ArticlesController`. This allows you to put all admin-related actions in a specific place and all user-related actions in another.

There's more info on namespacing controllers in the Rails Guides here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing